# Python Plotting Graph with Groupby and Means

Tags: python, plot

```
Fruit Rate
Apple 4.7
Orange 4.6
Avocado 4.7
Cherry 4.7
Cherry 4.8
Apple 4.4
Banana 4.7
Banana 4.7
Orange 4.7
```

I have these two columns in the CSV file. I want to plot a graph with that two columns. But if the name of fruit is duplicate, only get one and their average rage (Distinct). For example, from my CSV file, the data will become

```
Fruit Rate
Apple 4.55
Orange 4.65
Avocado 4.7
Cherry 4.75
Banana 4.7
```

Then plotting the graph with new data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(PATH)
df = df.groupBy(['Fruit']).mean()
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Additional note:

You probably want the graph to be a bar chart. To do so change the line of plotting into this

```
df.plt.bar()
plt.show()
```

See more for modification of the bar chart [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)